# Flask - redirecting after file upload complete?

Tags: javascript, python, redirect, file-upload, flask

I'm trying to have user uploaded file groups on a project, and after all the uploads complete redirect to a different page. I'm using dropzone.js as the frontent and flask as the backend, in the backened files are handled like this: they are all sent in a single post requests, I iterate through this list with a for loop and save them as needed, and when the upload is done I need to redirect to a new page. I have the redirect set for after the for loop ends, but when I try to upload files with this none of them upload and I get a 302 error. Everything works normally without the redirect. Should I be using jQuery or something to monitor upload progress and tell the server when its complete?  Code looks something like this:

```
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files = request.files.getlist('f[]')
        for f in files: 
            do stuff
            save f

        return redirect (url_for('newpage', data="foo")

    return render_template("index.html")
```

Edit: actual redirect looks like this:

```
return redirect (url_for('display_gallery', gallery_id = gallery_id))
```

Comment: Is `newpage` the name of the method or the URL?

Comment: It was just fluff I put in to avoid having too much uncessesary stuff, edited to show my actual redirect.  Gallery ID is declared even though it isn't shown in my code so that isn't the problem.